# How to check data exists or not in array and add items to array using VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I always write data 【AAA, BBB, CCC】into CSV file.
I would like to also write other data (eg:DDD)
if there is in text file.

**An array:**
arr = Array("AAA", "BBB", "CCC")

**Text File(Read):**

```
AAA  
BBB  
CCC  
DDD  
BBB  
CCC  
AAA  
DDD  
AAA
```

**Code:**

```
Open InputFile For Input As #1  
Open OutputFile For Output As #2  
Do Until EOF(1)  
Line Input #1, strData  
'Read data from text file  
'Check text file data exists or not in arr  
'If not exist, add items(DDD) to arr  
Print #2, strData  
Loop  
Close #1  
Close #2
```

**CSV File(Write):**

```
AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD
```

What is the best way for doing this?

Comment: This question looks like a more detailed duplicate of [How to group data of text file using VBA](http://superuser.com/questions/690978/how-to-group-data-of-text-file-using-vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **[Filter Function (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fat7fw0s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)**
>   Returns a zero-based array containing a subset of a String array based on specified filter criteria.

1. Use the `filter` function and check the size of the resulting array with Ubound().
2. Use `Redim preserve` to expand your array by 1 and add your recently checked text value

Here is a small general example

```
Sub IsInArray()

    Dim arrCheck()

    arrInput = Array("AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD","BBB","CCC","AAA","DDD","AAA")
    arrCheck = Array("AAA","BBB","CCC")

    For Each Item In arrInput
        If UBound(Filter(arrCheck, Item)) = -1 Then
            ReDim Preserve arrCheck(UBound(arrCheck) + 1)
            arrCheck(UBound(arrCheck)) = Item
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```